# renderEvent from PHP JSON array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, fullcalendar

i am trying to [`renderEvent`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/) but it is not working.

here is what im trying to do:

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
// insert into db...

$array[] = ['start' => '2017-04-20', 'title' => 'Test Event'];
$json = json_encode($array);

echo $json;

?>
```

**javascript:**

```
<script>
// ...blah blah blah

request = $.ajax({
                url: "add_event.php",
                type: "post",
                data: serializedData
            });

            request.done(function (response){
                console.log('Insert successful.');

                // response variable is from the php echo: $json.

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', response); //this does not work
            });
</script>
```

As you can see, the response from `request.done` is not working. it is already a json and i want to insert into the renderEvent but it is not working.

the error i in my browser console is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
```

please help? thanks!

Comment: what actually gets returned as `response`? If it is empty then the php `if()` is not true

Comment: @charlietfl it is not empty...